# Java - MySQL - Create connection error

Tags: java, mysql

I don't know why but this line gives me an error. I'm first making a few private strings, host, port, database, user and password. Then I'm setting those strings in the constructor.

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + host + ":" + port + "/" + database + "?user=" + user + "&password=" + password);
```

This is the error message that I get:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: 
>   Cannot load connection class because of underlying exception:
>   'java.lang.Number FormatException: For input string: "null"'.

What did I do wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most likely cause is that one of your parameters is null. Probably `port`, since an attempt is made to convert it to a number.

Unless you are using a non default port (the default being 3306), you can just omit the port :

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + host + "/" + database + "?user=" + user + "&password=" + password);
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess, without seeing more code, is that `port` is `null`.

When you pass the string to the `getConnection()` method, it tries to parse out the port as a number. The when you concatenate a null value to a `String`, it appends 'null'. Now your string looks like `jdbc:mysql://examplehost:null`. Thus the `java.lang.Number FormatException: For input string: "null"`.

Answer (score 0):

Its preety much clear from the Exception. Its because your `port` is null and throws exception while tried to parse into Number.